# WPF list of events

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, routed-events

I am learning WPF now. My little programs need events for works correctly. I'm just learning and I know only events, which are in my book. I need your help guys. Where can I find list of events for of WPF program(for example: Click event, MouseLeftDown event)

Answer (score 1):

I use MS Visual Studio. The best way to see available events is to select the control in Design View, then view the Properties Window and select Events tab at the top. Hope this helps.